# Which paper to cite when referring to reservoir sampling *with replacement*?

Tags: reference-request, data-streams, citations, streaming-algorithms

As far as I can tell, the term "reservoir sampling" is commonly used to refer to sampling *without replacement* and references [1], [2], and [3] are cited while mentioning it. When referring to reservoir sampling *with replacement*, which papers should be cited? A recent reference that I found is titled "Reservoir-based Random Sampling with Replacement from Data Stream" available at http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972740.53.

[1] Donald E. Knuth: The Art of Computer Programming, Volume II: Seminumerical Algorithms, 2nd Edition. Addison-Wesley 1981, ISBN 0-201-03822-6

[2] McLeod, A.I., Bellhouse, D.R.: A convenient algorithm for drawing a simple random sample. Appl, Stat., pp. 182-184 (1983).

[3] Jeffrey Scott Vitter: Random Sampling with a Reservoir. ACM Trans. Math. Softw. 11(1): 37-57 (1985)